# Using Django's select_related() with multi-column foreign keys

Tags: django, join, foreign-keys, django-orm

I have a multitenancy app which uses shared tables for all tenants (there's only one database and only one schema).

My tables are storing entities from remote systems of various customers, and all of these entities have an effective primary key of (tenant, remote_id):

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    company_name = models.TextField()

class Post(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
    remote_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('tenant', 'remote_id'))
        index_together = (('tenant', 'remote_id'))
```

(So technically, I have autoincrementing integer primary keys, but it doesn't really matter for my question and I could remove them if that made a difference.)

Among each other, the entities reference each other by remote ID, the tenant is always the same (there's no cross-referencing between tenants):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
    remote_id = models.IntegerField()
    post_remote_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('tenant', 'remote_id'))
        index_together = (('tenant', 'remote_id'))
```

Django doesn't support multi-value foreign keys, so I couldn't declare my 'foreign keys' as such.

Now when retrieving entities from my local database, I would like to retrieve the foreign key-referenced entities in the same query via an SQL JOIN. Normally, you would use Django's [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this, but as I haven't declared them as foreign keys, I can't use this.

Here's an example of what I would like to do (and have it hit the database with only one query!):

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(author='Ernest').select_related()
commented_post_titles = [comment.post.title for comment in comments]
```

Is there another way to get something equivalent in a clean way? I could override the manager class and execute custom SQL with the JOIN. But how do I cleanly create the model instances and make them link each other without breaking Django's model system entirely?

My preferred solution would of course be some kind of `models.ForeignKey` subclass, which behaves just like the regular foreign key (supporting select_related(), traversing, etc.) but takes the additional `tenant` column condition into account. Could something like that be written?

To emphasize: these are simple 1-to-n relations. It's possible that the referenced entity does not yet exist in my local database (that's why I'm not transforming these relationships into artificial foreign keys in the first place), but there's guaranteed to be exactly 0..1 related entities, never multiple ones.

Comment: I've just found out about Django's [CurrentSiteManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#the-currentsitemanager), which appears to do something similar. I didn't get around to checking its source code as to whether there's something I could adapt to solve my problem.